# Play audio in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, playback

I have a 6467584*1 double array containing audio data. The sampling frequency for the data is 256. When I try to play the audio using the `soundsc` function it shows the following error   :

> Error using sound (line 76) Device Error: Invalid sample rate. Error in soundsc (line 55)
>
> sound(varargin{:});

Is there any function that I can use in MATLAB to play audio?

Comment: You should post the relevant portion of your code: how do you call `soundsc`? What are the input?

Answer (score 1):

If you look into [documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/soundsc.html) of `soundsc`:

> **Fs**: Sample rate, in hertz, of audio data y, is specified as a positive number from 1000 through 384000. Valid values depend on both the sample rates permitted by MATLAB® and the specific audio hardware on your system. MATLAB has a hard restriction of 1000 Hz <= Fs <= 384000 Hz, although further hardware-dependent restrictions apply.

It's not strange then that with sampling frequency of 256Hz you get the error...

### Solution:

Use one of the sampling frequencies supported by your sound card. Available devices and sampling frequencies which they support can be checked using function `audiodevinfo`.

When frequency at which your data was sampled doesn't match any of  sampling frequencies supported by your sound card, you need to (up/down)sample it to have it played with the "correct" speed and pitch.

### Alternatives for `audiosc`:

- `audio` which is basically the same as `audiosc` but doesn't scale/normalize your data
- `audioplayer`
- some third-party libraries like for example [pa-wavplay](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47336-pa-wavplay-for-32-bit-and-64-bit)